# force pandas to read nan as string

Tags: python, pandas

I could not find any other question related to mine. Please help me with a link, if I missed it...

I have a csv-file looking like this:

```
"concentration"
"5"
"5"
"5"
"5"
"5"

"nan"
"nan"
"nan"
"nan"
"nan"
```

If I read it with pandas read_csv, the "nan" values are automatically interpreted as NaN. But I would like to keep them as a string. The missing value which should be NaN is in line 7 (where actually nothing is written).

I tried to read it like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, dtype= {'concentration': 'string'}, quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, sep=',')
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you can use `keep_default_na` and `na_values`. From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html):

```
na_values : list-like or dict, default None
Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific per-column NA values

keep_default_na : bool, default True
If na_values are specified and keep_default_na is False the default NaN values are overridden, otherwise they’re appended to
```

So here's the code

```
pd.read_csv('c:\\temp\\temp.txt', keep_default_na=False, na_values=[''])

   concentration
0              5
1              5
2              5
3              5
4              5
5            NaN
6            nan
7            nan
8            nan
9            nan
10           nan
```

Comment: And if you want to specify others, this can with `na_values`